# How plot $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{1-y}$ with $x^2+y^2<1$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, mathematica, maple

How do you  plot $$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{1-y} \text{with}~ x^2+y^2<1$$ in Mathematica or Maple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Mathematica* (version 6 or newer)

```
Plot3D[x/(1 - y), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
       RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

Comment: Beautiful man, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Maple, you can use the following codes:

```
[> with(plots):
  plot3d(x/(1-y), x = -1 .. 1, y = -sqrt(1-x^2) .. sqrt(1-x^2), axes = boxed, filled = true,numpoints = 1000,color=green);
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to embed a Mathematica figure here so that one can rotate it and stuff?

Comment: @LoveLearning: Sorry I donno the way for it. :-(

Comment: Do you know how to find the max value (e.g. via Lagrange multipliers) in Mathematica?

Comment: @LoveLearning: I am used to it long ago, but there is a package about it in Maple.